# Cannot get CakePHP 3.8 multiple file upload to work

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, multiple-file-upload, cakephp-3.8

I'm working on this project and at first it has a single file upload that works perfectly fine, but had to change to multiple file upload and now I just can't make it work!
Getting an "Headers aready sent" error:

```
Deprecated (16384): Accessing `here` as a property will be removed in 4.0.0. Use request->getAttribute("here") instead. - /home1/thecyb80/seibo.the-cyberpunk.com/src/Controller/AppController.php, line: 92
 You can disable deprecation warnings by setting `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your config/app.php. [CORE/src/Core/functions.php, line 311]

Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=/home1/thecyb80/seibo.the-cyberpunk.com/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php line=856 [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 51]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/thecyb80/seibo.the-cyberpunk.com/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:856) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 152]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/thecyb80/seibo.the-cyberpunk.com/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:856) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 185]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/thecyb80/seibo.the-cyberpunk.com/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:856) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 185]
```

Here's my code: `add.ctp`

```
<?= $this->Form->create($atividade, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
```

[...]

```
<div class="form-group m-0">
    <label class="btn btn-light p-3 rounded border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column" style="cursor: pointer; min-height: 350px;">
        <strong class="d-block">Selecione o(s) arquivo(s) da atividade. Você pode enviar até 10 arquivos.</strong>
        <span class="exercicio-nome d-flex aling-items-center justify-content-center w-100 mt-3"></span>
        <?= $this->Form->file('arquivos[]', [ 'class' => 'exercicio-item', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'display: none;', 'label' => [ 'class' => 'd-none' ] ]) ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

Validation founded in `AtividadesTable.php` (that's the only occurrence of the field):

```
$validator
    ->scalar('arquivos')
    ->maxLength('arquivos', 255)
    ->allowEmptyString('arquivos')
    ->allowEmptyFile('arquivos');
```

I've tried several solutions, that I've found over the internet, but none helped me. I'm using CakePHP 3.8.11 over PHP 7.2.31.

Here'se my `composer.json` modules installed (don't know if it can help):

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.8.*",
    "cakephp/migrations": "^2.0.0",
    "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.0",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*"
}
```

Since I can't go over this step, I'm assuming that for now, my Controller is irrelevant. What can I do?

---

Edit: 06/04 (asked by [Salines](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127933/salines))

### Multiple file upload (uploaded 4 files)

Using

```
<?= $this->Form->file('arquivos[]', [ 'class' => 'exercicio-item', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'display: none;', 'label' => [ 'class' => 'd-none' ] ]) ?>
```

Output

```
(Page just refreshs)
```

### Single file upload

Using

```
<?= $this->Form->file('arquivos[]', [ 'class' => 'exercicio-item', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'display: none;', 'label' => [ 'class' => 'd-none' ] ]) ?>
```

Output

```
(Page just refreshs)
```

### Multiple file upload (uploaded 4 files)

Using

```
<?= $this->Form->file('arquivos', [ 'class' => 'exercicio-item', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'display: none;', 'label' => [ 'class' => 'd-none' ] ]) ?>
```

Output

```
 /src/Controller/AtividadesController.php (line 159)

[
    'nome' => 'Atividade teste',
    'status' => '1',
    'users' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '306'
        ]
    ],
    'turmas' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '17'
        ]
    ],
    'materias' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '45'
        ]
    ],
    'descricao' => '<p>Teste</p>
',
    'comeca_dia' => [
        'year' => '2020',
        'month' => '06',
        'day' => '04'
    ],
    'termina_dia' => [
        'year' => '2020',
        'month' => '06',
        'day' => '04'
    ],
    'video' => '',
    'aviso_do_professor' => 'Teste',
    'arquivos' => [
        'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpafKkWr',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'name' => 'imagem_sobre.png',
        'type' => 'image/png',
        'size' => (int) 600995
    ]
]
```

### Multiple file upload (uploaded 4 files)

Using

```
<?= $this->Form->file('arquivos. ', [ 'class' => 'exercicio-item', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'display: none;', 'label' => [ 'class' => 'd-none' ] ]) ?>
```

Output

```
(Page just refreshs)
```

### AtividadesController

I'll show my `AtividadesController.php` (add method):

```
/**
* Add method
*
* @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
*/
public function add($nivelId = null)
{
    $atividade = $this->Atividades->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        // Edit - StackOverflow
        debug($this->getRequest()->getData()); exit;

        $atividade = $this->Atividades->patchEntity($atividade, $this->request->getData());

        die(debug($_FILES));

        // Salvando os arquivos
        if (!empty($_FILES['arquivos']['name'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['arquivos'];
            $arquivoName = $file['name'];
            $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

            $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($arquivoName, '.')), 1);
            $arr_ext = array('zip', 'rar', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx');

            if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) {
                $imgHashed = md5($arquivoName) . time() . '.' . $ext;
                $fileDir = WWW_ROOT . 'files/' . $userId;

                if (!is_dir($fileDir)) {
                    mkdir($fileDir);
                }

                @move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $fileDir . '/' . $imgHashed);

                $atividade['arquivos'] = $imgHashed;
                $atividade['arquivo_nome'] = $arquivoName;
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__("Só aceitamos imagens dos tipos 'zip', 'rar', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'ppt' ou 'pptx'."));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
            }
        }

        if ($this->Atividades->save($atividade)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('A atividade foi salva.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index', $this->Auth->user('id')]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('A atividade não pode ser salva. Por favor, tente novamente.'));
    }

    $arquivos = $this->Atividades->Arquivos->find('list');
    $materias = $this->Atividades->Materias->find('list');

    if ($nivelId) {
        $turmas = $this->Atividades->Turmas->find('list')->matching('Nivels', function($q) use ($nivelId) {
            return $q
                ->select()
                ->where(['Nivels.id' => $nivelId]);
        });
    } else {
        $turmas = $this->Atividades->Turmas->find('list');
    }
    $users = $this->Atividades->Users->find('list')->where(['tipo' => 'professor']);
    $this->set(compact('atividade', 'arquivos', 'materias', 'turmas', 'users'));
}
```

Am I missing something? Some CakePHP component, maybe? Some PHP extension?

Comment: Why would you assume that your controller is irrelevant, when the error points to exactly that, to your controller, specifically to `AppController`, line `92`? The error message also tells you how to fix it.

Comment: In `AppController`, line 92, is just a warning... The Controller I mean is `AtividadesController`, which is the Controller associated with this View.... But, anyway, here's the line highlighted:

`return $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->request->here);`

Comment: It's just a warning, yes, but that warning is being output, which causes headers to be sent, and that's why you receive the folowup warnings. As mentioned, the error message tells you how to fix it, use `->getAttribute("here")` instead of `->here`, or disable deprecation warnings.

Comment: I've changed the property to `request->getAttribute("here")` as its recommends, but still not working. Just the warnings dismissed.

Comment: Tried to add a `debug($_FILES)` inside Controller to see if anything happens, but it seems like this field isn't being sent in form data... It's strange 'cause when it was just a single file, it worked without any trouble! I'm still trying to get solutions over the internet, but it seems like I'm the unlucky guy who have a problem that anyone has ever had... Or I'm just too stupid to see something that is right there...

Comment: in controller try `debug($this->getRequest()->getData());  exit;`  for single and multiple upload and post results in your question